# 09 ford f-150 misfire cyl.5 and 7 only has spark and pulse only went is hot

Tags: ford, ignition, misfire, f-150

this hapen after drive the truck for 10 to 20 minutes went stop star misfire at idle only 5 and 7 cyl. has spark and injector pulse if i race the rpm couple time the engine star run normal again

Comment: Have you had the computer scanned? Please post the codes if there are any.

Comment: does the truck have cylinder deactivation? i'd have to look it up but i think those are the cylinders that are supposed to shut down when at a stop. also what engine does it have?